# Нужна ли запятая перед "или"? (3)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, или

> В нашем интернет-магазине можно легко купить запасные части для
>   грузовиков и полуприцепов, воспользовавшись удобным поиском по VIN
>   коду или по заданным параметрам.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь союз *или* соединяет однородные члены предложения (по коду, по параметрам — варианты "поиска"). Запятая не нужна.